# Jquery UI dialog not getting closed when clicked outside of it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to close the jQuery dialog when clicked anywhere outside the dialogue box

I have tried with this code:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  modal: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  height: "auto",
  width: "auto",
  open: function() {
    jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
      jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
    })
  }
});
```

But it is not able to close the Jquery diaog when clicked anywhere outside the box

http://jsfiddle.net/ovog4njt/30/

I dont have any custom css as mentioned in the fiddle pointed by OP

Comment: Why are you using `.ui-widget-overlay` selector? There's no such element. Also, you are using old jQuery UI version which cause errors.

Comment: i have taken some fiddle and used my code in it , so i dont know about version exactly.

Comment: I have taken the answer from the duplicate link pointed by OP and whic aren't working (  open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function()       {
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because `modal` is set to `false`, which means that there is no `.ui-widget-overlay` element. To resolve this, you could simply set `modal` to `true` when initializing the dialog, and it will work as expected. [(updated example)](http://jsfiddle.net/uqfmd8w8/)

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  modal: true
  // ...
});
```

---

However, if you can't change that for some reason, or if you don't want the dialog to be a modal, an alternative would be to attach a `click` event listener to the `document`, and determine whether `event.target` is inside of the dialog element:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8onr2pe/)

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  modal: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  height: "auto",
  width: "auto",
  open: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(document).one('click', function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length) {
        $(self).dialog('close');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

You will also need to stop immediate propagation when opening the dialog in order to prevent it from being closed immediately:

```
$('#open').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
});
```